# If I create a new List<T> from an existing list, are the members equal?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Assuming I have a `List<Stuff> listA` that has some items in it. I create a second list as follows:

```
List<Stuff> listB = new List<Stuff>(listA);
```

Let's say I have an item from `listA`, and I try to remove it from `listB`:

```
Stuff itemFromA = listA[0];
listB.Remove(itemFromA);
```

Assuming `Stuff` is a Class, should the item be successfully removed from `listB`? In other words, are the members the same objects or does the process of creating a new list clone the items?

I am experiencing behaviour in some code I'm debugging where the `.Remove` fails to remove the item from `listB`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [List<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) does not clone the items.

For value types the value is copied, for reference types a reference to the same object is added to the list.

```
List<object> listA = new List<object>();
listA.Add(new object());

List<object> listB = new List<object>(listA);
bool result = object.ReferenceEquals(listA[0], listB[0]);

// result == true
```

Comment: Unless T is a struct, where the value is copied, not referenced.

Comment: Great thanks, that's what I thought as well. There must be some other code behind the scenes thats causing the .Remove to fail then, cheers!

Comment: codekaizen - yeah I suspected that too but checked and its class. thanks as well